# Saving each DataFrame column to separate CSV files

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have some dataframes, one of them is the following:

```
L_M_P = pd.read_csv('L_M_P.csv')  # dimensions 17520x33
```

I would like to be able to save each column as an independent csv file, without having to do it manually as follows:

```
L_M_P[:,0].to_csv('column0.csv')
L_M_P[:,1].to_csv('column1.csv')
...
```

In that case, I would have 33 new '.csv' files, each with dimensions 17520x1.

Comment: you should say which language - R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through columns and write it to files.

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column].to_csv(column + '.csv')
```

**Note**: Assuming language to be python as the question has pd mentioned in it and all mentioned code is part of pandas